# Как сделать дубликаты страны для каждого года в python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, структуры-данных, обработка

Даны данные по ВВП для 140 стран с 1991 по 2015 год. Таблица выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Импортирование этой таблицы в python:

```
`import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\803008\\Desktop\\Project')
df1 = pd.ExcelFile("Stat.xlsx")
df1.sheet_names
['\u041b\u0438\u0441\u04421', '\u041b\u0438\u0441\u04422']
df = df1.parse('\u041b\u0438\u0441\u04421')`
```

Для анализа данных нужно для совместить индексы по годам для каждой страны, чтобы в результате получилось три колонки: Название стран (с дубликатами, т.к. одной стране соответствует данные за несколько лет), год и ВВП (GDP):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать дубликаты страны для каждого года в python чтобы получился результат в трёх колонках с тремя переменными для python?
(есть проблема с чтением названия стран на русском языку в python: `\u0410\u0432)

```
print(r)
```

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\803008\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 65-73: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: Вы можете выложить исходный excel file?

Comment: Ссылка на исходный эксель файл: `https://www.dropbox.com/s/dq7i7dlezwhny7q/Stat.xlsx?dl=0`

Comment: у вас там две вкладки (sheets) - вас какая интересует?

Comment: Первая вкладка, она называется: "1". Просто вторую вкладку можно было бы по аналогии обработать

Comment: `pd.read_excel()` читает первую (по порядку) по умолчанию... Кстати легче указать порядковый номер влкадки (начиная с 0) - `pd.read_excel(filename, sheetname=1)` - для второй

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так:

```
fn = r'D:\download\Stat.xlsx'
# CodePage: 1251    
df = pd.read_excel(fn, index_col=0, skiprows=[1], encoding='cp1251').dropna(how='all')
```

или:

```
# UTF-8 encoding
df = pd.read_excel(fn, index_col=0, skiprows=[1], encoding='utf-8').dropna(how='all')
```

потом:

```
r = df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0':'Country','level_1':'Year',0:'GDP'})

print(r)
```

Результат:

```
        Country                 Year                  GDP
0     Австралия                 1991                18912
1     Австралия                 1992                19654
2     Австралия                 1993                20727
3     Австралия                 1994                21983
4     Австралия                 1995                22819
5     Австралия                 1996                23952
6     Австралия                 1997                25165
7     Австралия                 1998                26341
8     Австралия                 1999                27581
9     Австралия                 2000                28770
...         ...                  ...                  ...
3683        NaN                 2008                 2008
3684        NaN                 2009                 2009
3685        NaN                 2010                 2010
3686        NaN                 2011                 2011
3687        NaN                 2012                 2012
3688        NaN                 2013                 2013
3689        NaN                 2014                 2014
3690        NaN                 2015                 2015
3691        NaN  Изменение за 10 лет  Изменение за 10 лет
3692        NaN  Изменение за 10 лет                    %

[3693 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Все работает! Но у вас правильно отображаются названия стран и NaN, у меня ошибка: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\803008\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp850.py"` Что это может быть, не хватает в библиотеке пайтона модуля для языка или проблема с кодировкой?

Comment: попробуйте `pd.read_excel(..., encoding='cp1251')`...

Comment: Страны всё равно остаются в такой странной кодировке: `\u0410\u0432`, но в ошибке поменялась ссылка на линию в которой она произошла: `>>> print(r)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\803008\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 65-73: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: Какая у вас версия Pandas и что показывает `print(sys.getdefaultencoding())`?

Comment: # python: 3.5.2.final.0 # python-bits: 64 # pandas: 0.17.1, а по поводу команды: `print(sys.getdefaultencoding())` я получаю =>
`File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined`

Comment: `sys` надо сначала импортировать - `import sys`. Pandas 0.17.1 - очень старая версия. Актуальная версия 0.19.2 и вот-вот выйдет 0.20.0

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54649/discussion-between-user21-and-maxu).

Comment: Я обновил все пакеты, включая pandas: pandas: 0.19.2. Но ошибка остаётся: 
`>>> print(r) 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
File "C:\Users\803008\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode 
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]` 
Страны выглядят как и раньше: 
` Country Year GDP 
0 \u0410\u0432\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u043b\u0438\u044f 1991 18912 `

Comment: @user21, посмотрите [этот вопрос и ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050292/prevent-encoding-errors-in-python)

Comment: Я не доконца понял в чём была проблема. Кажется часть переменных  была в формате str. Я выгрузил всё в spyder и попробовал код предложенный вами в ссылке, поменяв название файла для перекодировки и получился желаемый результат: `r.head(5)
Out[10]: 
     Country  Year    GDP
0  Австралия  1991  18912
1  Австралия  1992  19654`

Comment: @user21, скорее всего проблема была в шрифте по-умолчанию для консольного окна (терминала). Я всегда ставлю "Lucida Console" по умолчанию