# Как перевести столбцы в строки в pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Нужно сделать операцию, обратную  приведенной по ссылке
[Как сделать дубликаты страны для каждого года в python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/634323/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-python[/url]), то есть из столбцов во втором скриншоте, сделать строки как в первом?

Answer (score 1):

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,(10,3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [19]: df
Out[19]:
   a  b  c
0  3  3  3
1  1  1  4
2  2  0  1
3  2  0  1
4  0  3  0
5  3  0  0
6  4  0  1
7  4  4  2
8  4  4  4
9  1  1  2
```

Теперь сделаем из значений столбца `a` - индекс, из `b` - столбцы, `c` - значения (дупликаты будут просуммированны)

[pivot_table()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) метод:

```
In [20]: df.pivot_table(index='a', columns='b', values='c', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
Out[20]:
b  0  1  3  4
a
0  0  0  0  0
1  0  6  0  0
2  2  0  0  0
3  0  0  3  0
4  1  0  0  6
```

[groupby()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + агрегатная функция + [unstack()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
In [21]: df.groupby(['a','b']).sum().unstack('b', fill_value=0)
Out[21]:
   c
b  0  1  3  4
a
0  0  0  0  0
1  0  6  0  0
2  2  0  0  0
3  0  0  3  0
4  1  0  0  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Транспонировать датафрейм:

```
df = df.transpose()
```